# How To config Current Context from BaseContext with Inheritance (The entity type Person is not part of the model for the current context.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Current Context and I Will want to Inheritance from Base DataBaseContext . I have a Generic Repository Pattern and also I  build a framework for Handle All Project . Now my Base Context is

```
public class DataBaseContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public DataBaseContext(): base("name=DataBaseContext")
    {
        this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
        //  Database.SetInitializer<DataBaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DataBaseContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }       

    public Task<int> CommitAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DbSet<TSet> GetDbSet<TSet>() where TSet : class
    {
       return this.Set<TSet>();
    }

    public void RolebackAllChanges()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }      
}
```

and My Current Context in one of the Subsystem is

```
public class TestJirProjectContext : DataBaseContext
{
    public TestJirProjectContext() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DataBaseContext>(null);
        //  this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookEntityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonEntityConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    // Create DbSet 
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Now I use from Person Service and Call Person Repository and  finally I use from Generic Method (for example GetAll )

and I get a error in this line

```
  public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
  {
      return this.Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList().AsQueryable();
  }
```

And my error text is

> Additional information: The entity type Person is not part of the model for the current context.

How to Unification of two contexts ?

Comment: thank you for your replay sam-axe

Comment: Please show your code for `PersonEntityConfiguration` class, ensure you have `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person");` setting inside that class.

Comment: **Not** work for me , My PersonEntityConfiguration is :                                             `public class PersonEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonEntityConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("Person");
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");

        }
    }`

Comment: I found Problem. I did not use from `TestJirProjectContext` in   `container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, TestJirProjectContext>();`